# Number of keys in ReadableMap?

Tags: java, reactjs, native

I know this seems like an obvious question but how do you count the number of keys in a ReadableMap in java in react-native?  I tried this method but it doesn't seem to work for some reason:

```
public int getNumKeys(ReadableMap RM) {
    int numKeys = 0;
    ReadableMapKeySetIterator keyIterator = RM.keySetIterator();
    while (keyIterator.hasNextKey()) {
        numKeys++;
    }
    return numKeys;   
}
```

Do I have to use a ReadableNativeMap?

Answer (score 1):

Oh stupid I was not getting the next key well this might help somebody out.

```
public int getNumKeys(ReadableMap RM) {
    int numKeys = 0;
    ReadableMapKeySetIterator keyIterator = RM.keySetIterator();
    while (keyIterator.hasNextKey()) {
        numKeys++;
        keyIterator.nextKey();
    }
    return numKeys;   
}
```